# Why is the latency of my GAE app serving static files so high?

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, go

I was checking the performance of my Go application on GAE, and I thought that the response time for a static file was quite high (183ms). Is it? Why is it? What can I do about it?

```
64.103.25.105 - - [07/Feb/2013:04:10:03 -0800] "GET /css/bootstrap-responsive.css
HTTP/1.1" 200 21752 - "Go http package" "example.com" ms=183 cpu_ms=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Regular" 200 ms seems on the high side of things for static files. I serve a static version of the same "bootstrap-responsive.css" from my application and I can see two types of answer times:

- 50-100ms (most of the time)
- 150-500ms (sometimes)

Since I have a ping roundtrip of more or less 50ms to google app engine, it seems the file is usually served within 50ms or so.

I would guess the 150-300ms response time is related to google app engine frontend server being "cold cached". I presumed that retrieving the file from some persistent storage, involves higher latencies than if it is in the frontend server cache.

I also assume that you can hit various frontend servers and get sporadic higher latencies.

Lastly, the overall perceived latency from a browser should be closely approximated by:
(tc)ping round trip + tcp/http queuing/buffering at the frontend server + file serving application time (as seen in your google app logs) + time to transfer the file.

If the frontend server is not overloaded and the file is small, the latency should be close to ping + serving time.

In my case, 50ms (ping) + 35ms (serving) = 85ms, is quite close to what I see in my browser 95ms.

Finally, If your app is serving a lot of requests, they maybe get queued, introducing a delay that is not "visible" in the application logs.

Answer (score 1):

For a comparison I tested a site using [tools.pingdom.com](http://tools.pingdom.com)

Pingdom reported a Load time of `218ms`

Here was the result from the logs:

```
2013-02-11 22:28:26.773 /stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css 200 35ms 45kb
```

Another test resulting in `238ms` from Pingdom and `2ms` in the logs.

Therefore, I would say that your `183ms` seems relatively good. There are so many factors at play:

- Your location to the server
- Is the server that is serving the resource overloaded?

You could try serving the files using a Go instance instead of App Engine's static file server. I tested this some time ago, the results were occasionally faster, but the speeds were less consistent. Response time also increased under load, due to [App Engine Instance being Limited to 10 Concurrent Requests](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7927). Not to mention you will be billed for the instance time.

**Edit:**

For a comparison to other Cloud / CDN providers see [Cedexis's - Free Country Reports](http://www.cedexis.com/country-reports/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try [setting caching on static files](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Static_Cache_Expiration).

Comment: Thank you, but that's not quite what I wanted. I believe not setting it will give me 10 minutes default? I assumed (and please correct me if I'm wrong) that serving a static file would take on the order of milliseconds. Or am I misinterpreting the result? Could it be the download speed that limits it - I should test with an empty file.