# Why is app engine latency so big?

Tags: google-app-engine

Why does it take so much time to download a static file from GAE? The same is with responses from my application, they have huge latency, but to exclude delays in my code I publish here access times to static.

Time to download http ://t***p.appspot.com/favicon.ico

[image: Static file download latency]

Ping from me to the GAE front is

ping t***p.appspot.com

```
PING appspot.l.google.com (173.194.71.141) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lb-in-f141.1e100.net (173.194.71.141): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=28.1 ms
64 bytes from lb-in-f141.1e100.net (173.194.71.141): icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=28.0 ms
```

Comment: No idea, the amount of time varies a lot, and I see a typical 30-80ms difference compared with my ping times.  Are you using a static handler and is it a static file or static dir handler ?

Comment: @TimHoffman, I use "static_files: static/favicon.ico"

Comment: Note that static handlers will not start a new instance, so that is not the problem here.  I would compare latencies for static_dir vs static_files in case there is some varience there.  Having said that, on inactive sites static handlers can still take as much as 300ms - I have an example site that shows this.  Whereas an active site seems to take only 40ms, and this probably is due  google's own caching for static handlers and edge caches.

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine is based on Instances.

**How AE Instances work?**

1. When http request is received AE starts new instance (if no instance is available), it takes time for instance to get ready to receive the request.
2. When Instance get job done with the request, it stays in half-off state for 30mins (by default).
3. When other request is received, half-off instance will get ready much faster than the one which is completely off.

If the request (which timing you have presented) was the first one for some time, AE had to boot up new instance.

**Edit:**
I've found similar question to yours: [Why is the latency of my GAE app serving static files so high?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754850/why-is-the-latency-of-my-gae-app-serving-static-files-so-high)

One of the ideas presented by [Kyle Finley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14825651/2471388) is to serve files through your script rather
than setting them to be static (as Finley reports, results are occasionally better but the speed is less consistent).
Other idea is to enable/increase caching for static files. [GAE Application Configuration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig)

Comment: It was not the first one

Comment: This answer is not relevant to static handlers only running code. Static file requests will not start an instance of appengine. I can prove this is necessary.  static handlers are served using different infrastructure.

Comment: @Tim, I know that, I'll fix my answer so it won't be misleading.